# Runtime error claiming a negative or zero argument to the logarithm function in Box-Mueller algorithm

Tags: debugging, fortran, runtime-error, fortran90

The following code is a part of a Fortran 90 program that I wrote in Plato IDE: 
It is just the Box-Mueller algorithm to generate Gaussian random numbers.

```
Program brownstep2_single_stage
  Integer:: i,j,m,n,countsucc!,a
  Real:: dt,D,epsa,r1,r2,w,fptsum,fptdef1,fptdef2
  Real,Dimension(0:100002) :: fx !gt
  !T=1000.0 and n*dt=T
  dt=0.001
  m=100000
  n=100000
  D=1.0
  !a=7
  w=2
  epsa=0.00001
  fx(0)=6.0
  !gt(0)=0
  fptsum=0
  countsucc=0
  Call random_seed()
  Do i=0,m
    !Call random_seed(a)

    Do j=0,n
      Do while (w>=1.0.and.w<0.0)
        Call random_number(r1)
        Call random_number(r2)
        !r=rand()
        r1=2.0*r1-1
        r2=2.0*r2-1
        w=r1*r1+r2*r2
      End do
      w=sqrt((-2.0*log(w))/w)
      r1=r1*w
      r2=r2*w

      If(mod(j,2)==0) then
        w=r1
      Else if(mod(j,2)==1) then
        w=r2
      End if
      fx(j+1)=fx(j)+w*sqrt(2.0*D*dt)
      If(fx(j+1)<epsa) then
        fptsum=fptsum+(j+1)*dt
        countsucc=countsucc+1
        exit
      End if
      print *,i,j
    End do
  End do
  fptdef1=fptsum/m
  fptdef2=fptsum/countsucc
  print *,'The value of fpt by 1st definition is:',fptdef1
  print *,'The value of fpt by 2nd definition is:',fptdef2
  print *,'The number of successful events is:',countsucc
  print *,'The total number of events is:',m
End program brownstep2_single_stage
```

During compilation, it shows no error, but when run, it shows the following runtime error, claiming a negative or zero argument to the logarithm function.

```
Runtime error from program:e:\my files\sample2brownstep_gauss.exe
Run-time Error
Error: Negative or zero argument to logarithm routine

 BROWNSTEP2_SINGLE_STAGE -  in file sample2brownstep_gauss.f90 at line 31 [+02cc]
```

[image]

[image]

What should I do to avoid this?

Comment: Do you ever ensure `w` is not negative?  That is, how do you initially set the value of `w`?  If `w` is equal to `-2.`, say, before entering the `j`-controlled loop then you will indeed pass a negative valued argument to `log`.  If you want advice on that, you'll need to show a more thorough fragment.

Comment: @francescalus w is initialised at the beginning as w=2.

Comment: @francescalus Also added the runtime error message.

Comment: Could you also copy the message as text? Mainly for future visitors, because they may be searching the error message on the web. Try to do that always, avoid pictures for error messages wherever possible.

Comment: The error message says *"negative **or zero**"*!

Comment: @VladimirF Added the error message in text. And thanks for the edit.

Comment: Hi @SchrodingersCat  please make you example self-contained, including declarations and all. I tested your code with no issue at all, so that I cannot reproduce the error. Have you tested another compiler?

Comment: What does the new error picture mean? You can't just put there a picture without description. I suggest to print the values of the variables before computing the sqrt(log()). And, foremost, as Pierre de Buyl said, we need the **full code**! Please read [mcve]. It is now obvious we need one here.

Comment: could it be you declared `w` as integer? So then when it is smaller than 1, it's effectively 0? (gfortran and ifort complain when you do that, but I don't know what you're using and maybe it doesn't check variable types as restrictively)

Comment: This is *never* true.. `w>=1.0.and.w<0.0`  ( try  `.or.` )

Comment: @VladimirF Added the full code. And both the error pics are visible together.

Comment: I can't see IMPLICIT NONE there. That is probably the root of the problem.

Comment: @VladimirF Making the changes. I'll update as soon as I see some difference.

Comment: the root of the problem is he never enters the `while` loop, so as `r1,r2` are uninitialized and likely zero, `w` becomes zero ( or NAN ) on the second pass..

Comment: @agentp I don't understand why the program does not enter the do-while loop. Can you tell me?

Comment: `w` can not be both greater than 1 *and* less than zero ( see previous comment)

Comment: Yep, the original post had `do while (w>=1)`, which I use to test the code.

Answer (score 1):

The changed code above still has problems. w is still not set before the do while loop is reached for the first time and w is used in the condition. Use an 'infinite' do loop with an exit statement. This ensures that one attempt at w is **always** attempted. This would be better:

```
do
  Call random_number(r1)
  Call random_number(r2)
  r1=2.0*r1-1
  r2=2.0*r2-1
  w=r1*r1+r2*r2
  if (w .lt. 1.0) exit
End do
w=sqrt((-2.0*log(w))/w)
r1=r1*w
r2=r2*w
```